# MapServer Runtime Substitution | Omitting WHERE (in DATA) if no variable present

Tags: mapserver

I am using MapServer's RunTime Substitution.  They are a great feature.

In my case, I have layer setup pointing at a PostGIS table.  This layer is exposed via WMS.  I allow an optional query string variable in GetMap Requests (handled via Runtime Substitution) that ultimately is used in the Data SQL Query

```
VALIDATION
    "health"  "[a-zA-Z0-9,_]*$"
    "default_health" "'Good','Fair','Poor','Unknown'"
END

DATA "geom FROM (select * from foo where health IN (%health%)) as q using unique id using srid=4326"
```

In the above example, if no health variable is passed in via Runtime Substitution - I have a default that just builds an IN clause that encompasses all possible health values.  And this works.  My problem is I have other layers setup like this.  But these layers have many, many possible values.  So I end up having these monstrous IN clauses.

I am hoping someone can suggest a way that if a variable is not passed in via Runtime Substitution - I totally omit the where clause in my DATA line.  Is there some way to do a conditional IF in the MAPFILE?